# How to get <a href> elements with specific class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to bind some specific functions to specific links that have class "aMySpecialClass". Example:

```
<a href="#" class="aMySpecialClass"></a>
```

I tried several variations of the following code, no go...

```
jQuery('a').find('.aMySpecialClass').live(
    'click',
    function(event) {
        jQuery.fn.myfunction(this);
    });
```

Can jQuery find all the  using jQuery('a')?

edit: Noted that those links and classes aren't defined at run time, they are dynamically generated after the page is ready, it sends a query to the server, and with the results, it build those links with specific class afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to say it, but [**read the docs.**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) It's basically just [CSS selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Getting_Started).

```
jQuery('a.aMySpecialClass').on('click', function (event)
{
    jQuery.fn.myfunction(this);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `jQuery('a.aMySpecialClass')`?

Comment: Gotcha! This was it, I had to combine it with live afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('a.aMySpecialClass').live(
    'click',
    function(event) {
        jQuery.fn.myfunction(this);
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7. `.on()` should be used instead.  http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, thank you Smamatti. The function was able to get triggered after I generate them dynamically.

Comment: @MattBall You are right. Still using an old version and didn't think of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `find` you will be looking for elements *inside* the links. Just make a selector for both the tag and the class:

```
jQuery('a.aMySpecialClass')
```